# Android Twitter conversion tracking through MoPub SDK issue

Tags: android, twitter, mopub, twitter-fabric, conversion-tracking

I integrated Twitter conversion tracking through MoPub SDK and also I integrated Fabric SDK through Eclipse.
I am facing issue that It not track my App.

I added

```
new MoPubConversionTracker().reportAppOpen(this);
```

in My **onCreate()** method.

and also added Api key in **Manifest** file like this

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
        android:value="API-KEY" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.mopub.mobileads.MraidActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.mopub.common.MoPubBrowser"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.mopub.mobileads.MraidVideoPlayerActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />
```

What else i missed? Or what the issue?